# Is there a default copyright license on programming scripts released publicly on the internet without it's own license or one used by the website?

Tags: copyright

So i've been building a game and one of the scripts which does a major overhaul on the battle system has a Non-Commercial Creative Commons license on it but it does say that the Non-Commercial aspect of it can be waived by the author which i hope to get done.

there are some other scripts which i hope to use in my game. unlike this battle system overhaul i am confident i can rebuild these myself and add some feature to make using them easier for me to use (ie. one which records map status like chests opened, enemy types killed, etc, uses really long function name which i could shorten down. also i have to use a hack to get it to work with a disk change system) but time wise this would take me quite a while to rebuild.

these scripts however don't come with something like the Creative Commons within the script and the website i got them from didn't have an implied license for anything on the site (unlike say this site which says in the footer *"user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required"*)

now when i make the credits i will surely include the name they released the script under to show they're work was used however i don't want to be in violation of a default copyright license that i am unaware of if i am able to sell my game.

So is there a default copyright license on programming scripts released publicly on the internet without it's own license or one used by the website?

Answer (score 2):

There is no default license on anything. If there is no explicit license, then the material is protected by copyright and you have to directly ask the rights owner for permission to copy the script (which probably also means to use it, if it requires downloading).

Comment: Think of it like this: posting on the internet is like going out and leaving your front door open, both are stupid but neither gives someone the right to steal from you.